# What is the difference between idle3 and idle-python3.2

Tags: python, python3, idle-python

I installed them both via apt-get install and they seem to be the same. If I start them they both open up a python shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`idle3` is a package that depends on `idle-python3.3` and Python 3.3 (in Quantal, probably 3.2 in older Ubuntus) amongst other things. From the description (from `apt-cache show idle3`):

> This package is a dependency package, which depends on Debian's default
>    Python 3 version (currently v3.3).

---

The package itself provides a `/usr/bin/idle3` script which imports the library provided by the `idle-python3.3` package. `idle-python3.3` provides a version specific `/usr/bin/idle-python3.3` script too.

Answer (score 0):

`idle3` is a package that depends on `idle-python3.5`, `python3` and `python3-tk` (module for portable GUI with Tkinter).

Here is  a visualization of the dependency relationship between the differents packages.

[image]

```
debtree idle3 --max-depth= 3 | dot -Tpng > idle3.png
```